# Как реализовать такое окно в Android

Tags: android, android-layout, уведомления

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увидел в TODO LISt интересную вещь.

По нажатию на кнопку ВИДЖЕТА всплывает вот такое окно. При том что приложение не открывается, оно всплывает поверх начального экрана. 
Как такое сделать или хотя бы как искать информацию ?)

Answer (score 11):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Создайте класс наследник Dialog, создайте layout файл в котором опишите такую же разметку и в классе унаследованого от Dialog переопределите метод onCreate в котором выполните setContentView(//ваш latout//)

Comment: плохая идея. Использовать старые классы диалогов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать обычным DialogFragment с кастомным макетом в onCreateView.